# Unable to get Control id of sharepoint text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, sharepoint

I am trying to get the control id of my grid ... actually its looks like below :

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_6db898dd_6dee_4b80_913f_b8e92148008e_ctl00_gdvOption
```

But as i am writting a generalised code, i cannot do that above value hardcoded in the code

so i am tryting to do below:

```
var test1 = '<%= gdvOption1.UniqueID %>';
```

OR

```
var test2 = '<%= #gdvOption1.ClientID %>';
```

None of them giving the value .

the value of test1 and test2 will exactly what i writtern '<%= #gdvOption1.UniqueID %>';

and '<%= gdvOption1.ClientID %>';  ..respectively ...

Please help me ...

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried `var test2 = '<%= gdvOption1.ClientID %>';
` ??

Comment: use the http://mir.aculo.us/dom-monster/ dommonster to check for exposed variables (it may be availeble in the window object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works 100% for me:

```
 var test2 = document.getElementById("<%=gdvOption1.ClientID %>");
```